# Unable to attach css property dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

I want to show popup,but the popup is displaying scroll bar.
i am using Iframe to display the popup.

```
   var addPartnerDialog = App.addDialog("AddExistingPartner", 500, 250);      

 **$(addPartnerDialog.getId()).css('overflow','hidden');**


   var iframe = addPartnerDialog.load('/' + App.getVirtualDirectoryName() + '/PlatformPartner/EditPartner?Type=Add', function () {  

                iframe.contentWindow.editPartners.initialize(addPartnerDialog); 
            }); 
        }
```

The css property which is added is not applying to the html div.
Please let me now how can i achieve it.

Answer (score 1):

When you want to look up an element by id in jQuery (or in any CSS selector), the id has to be preceded by `#`:

```
$("#" + addPartnerDialog.getId()).css('overflow','hidden');
```

Alternatively, if you can get a DOM element reference from whatever sort of object "addPartnerDialog" refers to, you can pass that directly to jQuery and avoid the (not really expensive) id lookup.

Comment: @AJAYcHIGURUPATI If you don't describe exactly *how* something is "not working", nobody can help.

Comment: $("#" + addPartnerDialog.getId()).css('overflow','hidden');

Comment: I have tried with all this and it is not applying dynamically

Comment: @AJAYcHIGURUPATI well what is the value of `addPartnerDialog.getId()`? Is there an element in the page with that value as an id?

Comment: Yes, it is generated dynamically.I am able to see the div with that id and if i applied overflow property on the browser,it is working fine on the browser.When tried to apply dynamically,it is not working.